# Where are save games located for "Strong Bad's Cool Game For Attractive People"?

Tags: strongbads-cool-game

As the title says - where are the save-games located?

Comment: Have you checked in the Documents folder? A lot of games store their save data there.

Comment: @Wipqozn: Actually I asked this intending to answer it, in the hopes of saving others from  having to spend 15 unnecessary minutes figuring out how to transfer saves between two different versions of the game.  For some reason, they changed the save locations for the Steam version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The save game folders are in the following location

```
Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\My Documents\Telltale Games

Windows 7/Vista: C:\Users\<username>\Documents\Telltale Games
```

---

The folder-names for each game are different, depending on whether you bought the game directly from Telltale or on Steam.

If you bought the game directly from Telltale, the folder names are

```
Episode 1 - Homestar Ruiner
Episode 2 - Strong Badia the Free
Episode 3 - Baddest of the Bands
Episode 4 - Dangeresque 3
Episode 5 - 8-bit is Enough
```

If you bought the game on Steam, the folder-names are slightly different:

```
Homestar Ruiner
Strong Badia the Free
Baddest of the Bands
Dangeresque 3
8-bit is Enough
```

You can transfer save-games between the bought-directly-from-Telltale folders and the Steam folders, but the preferences don't seem to transfer correctly.